# Potential and Field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, curl

So given a field:

$$\vec E(r)=\frac{\alpha(\vec p \cdot \vec e_r)\vec e_r + \beta \vec p}{r^3}$$

where $α, β$ are constants, $\vec e_r$ is the unit vector in the direction $\vec r$, and $\vec p$ is a constant vector.

I'm supposed to find out the relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\vec E$ is a physical field.

My first instinct is, since the field s given in direction of $r$, I'm going to use spherical coordinates to make my life easier and then calculate $\nabla \times E = 0$.

I know that in spherical coordinates

$$\nabla \times E = \frac{1}{r\sin \theta} \Big\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin \theta V_{\theta}) - \frac{\partial V_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}\Big\} + \cdots$$

For obvious reasons, I'm not typing everything out.

My first question is, when we look at the field

$$\vec E(r)=\frac{\alpha(\vec p \cdot \vec e_r)\vec e_r + \beta \vec p}{r^3}$$

isn't this the same as

$$\vec E(r)=\frac{\alpha\vec p \cdot \vec e_r + \beta \vec p}{r^3}$$

because a unit vector dotted with itself is $1$?

My second question: the direction of the $P$ vector isn't given except in the first part, how do I relate it to $\theta$ head and $\phi$ head?

Third question (sorry for my shaky calculus foundation): taking the example of the first term of the curl of the field (which I typed out in LaTeX), since nothing in the $E$ field has a $\theta$ or $\phi$ term, the first term is $0$? I guess my insecurity about this assumption is because we have a constant vector pointing in some direction which unless is completely parallel to $r$ head we can relate its direction to $r$ head with appropriate $\theta$ and $\phi$ terms?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does it mean, to you, to figure out if a field is a _physical_ field? Maybe that it arises from a potential?

Comment: yes that, and the second part of this question asks me to derive the potential

Comment: $\vec p\cdot\vec e_r$ is a scalar. You can't add that to $\beta\vec p$, which is a vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the expression for the field only contains $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r$, it does not pin down a direction for $\theta = 0$, so we can choose it to be whatever is most convenient. In this case, the simplest choice is to be parallel to $\mathbf{p}$, the only preferred directon in the problem setup. Thus we will have $\mathbf{p} = p \hat{\mathbf{e}}_p$, where $\hat{\mathbf{p}}$ is the direction of $\theta = 0$ (in cylindrical coordinates, this would be $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_z$). This unit vector can be expressed as $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_p = \cos\theta \hat{\mathbf{e}}_r -\sin\theta \hat{\mathbf{e}}_\theta$. If you don't see why, try converting it to cylindrical coordinates. You'll find that you get $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_z$ as expected. This means $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r\cdot\mathbf{p} = p\cos\theta$, and we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) &=& \frac{\alpha p\cos\theta \hat{\mathbf{e}}_r + \beta p (\cos\theta \hat{\mathbf{e}}_r - \sin\theta\hat{\mathbf{e}}_\theta)}{r^3} \\&=& \frac{p}{r^3}\left[(\alpha + \beta)\cos\theta \hat{\mathbf{e}}_r - \beta\sin\theta \hat{\mathbf{e}}_\theta\right]
\end{eqnarray}
This doesn't depend on $\phi$ or have any $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_\phi$ component, so only the $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_\phi$ component of the curl can be nonzero. We can evaluate that as
\begin{eqnarray}
(\nabla\times\mathbf{E})_\phi &=& \frac{1}{r}\left[-\beta p\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{ \sin\theta}{r^3}\right) - (\alpha + \beta)p\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{r^3}\right)\right] \\&=& \frac{ p\sin\theta}{r^4}(\alpha +3\beta),
\end{eqnarray}
which means $\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = 0$ if $\alpha = -3\beta$, and the full expression for $\mathbf{E}$ is
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) =  -\frac{p\beta}{r^3}\left[2\cos\theta \hat{\mathbf{e}}_r + \sin\theta \hat{\mathbf{e}}_\theta\right].
$$
It's not too difficult from here to figure out what function $V$ gives $-\nabla V = \mathbf{E}$, so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this, wanted to ask how and why we can simply choose the diretion freely? i mean after all the field points in a certain direction and the constant vector points in a certain direction, if not mentioned in the text that they are parallel why can we choose for them to be parallel? in case not parallel then the vector would be affected by the field right? Sorry i waited a few days for the follow up (was kinda busy moving to a new place to live)

Comment: @Tomy It's important to remember that unlike the Cartesian unit vectors, $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r$ is *not* a constant vector. Since it always points directly away from the origin, its direction depends on where you are in space. As for the choice of coordinate system, because only $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r$ appears, the choice of the zero directions for $\theta$ and $\phi$ is not constrained. Similarly, if only $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ appeared and you wanted to use Cartesian, you could choose any direction perpendicular to that as $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$.

Comment: @Tomy I'll edit my explanation for why you can choose $\theta = 0$ to add some more detail.

Comment: hey sry dont mean to rush you but why can $\theta$ be 0?

Comment: @Tomy By the definition of spherical coordinates, there has to be *some* direction where $\theta = 0$.

Comment: yeah i get that but i mean the field has a direction and the vector has a direction too so the field is going to act on that vector, can we simply choose $\theta = 0$?

Answer (score 5):

For the first question, $\vec p\cdot\vec e_r$ is a *scalar* but $(\vec p\cdot\vec e_r)\vec e_r$ is a *vector* by elementwise multiplication, so you cannot simplify like that.

For the second question, there is no need to use explicit $p_r,p_\theta,p_\varphi$ components – without loss of generality set $\vec p$ in the same direction as $\theta=0$ (i.e. the $+z$-axis). Then (third question) $\vec p=p(\cos\theta,-\sin\theta,0)^T$, its dot product with $\vec e_r=(1,0,0)^T$ is $p\cos\theta$ and
$$\vec E=\frac p{r^3}\begin{bmatrix}
(\alpha+\beta)\cos\theta\\
-\beta\sin\theta\\
0\end{bmatrix}$$
The $\varphi$-component being zero, only that component of the curl will be nonzero and it equals
$$\frac{(rE_\theta)_r-(E_r)_\theta}r=p\cdot\frac{(2\beta\sin\theta)/r^3+((\alpha+\beta)\sin\theta)/r^3}r=\frac{p(\alpha+3\beta)\sin\theta}{r^4}$$
Thus $\vec E$ is irrotational iff $\alpha+3\beta=0$, in which case
$$\vec E=-\frac{p\beta}{r^3}\begin{bmatrix}
2\cos\theta\\
\sin\theta\\
0\end{bmatrix}=\nabla\frac{p\beta\cos\theta}{r^2}$$

Comment: Because this problem has axial symmetry, cylindrical is better than cartesian.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Hmm, you used spherical rather than cylindrical coordinates in your answer...

Comment: Yes but I'm kind of splitting the difference between cylindrical and spherical. Spherical has nicer functional forms but cylindrical has the actual $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ unit vector you need. Both approaches are better than cartesian though.